# Make script works for both input, is possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on this script that takes this as input:

```
{
   "success":true,
   "entities":[
      {
         "pais":{
            "id":2,
            "nombre":"Bolivia"
         }
      },
      {
         "pais":{
            "id":5,
            "nombre":"Colombia"
         }
      },
      {
         "pais":{
            "id":6,
            "nombre":"Costa Rica"
         }
      }
   ],
   "idToUpdate":"1"
}
```

And outputs this: *Bolivia, Colombia, Costa Rica*. Taking the input example I provide earlier this is how I call the function:

```
showList('#distTd-' + data.idToUpdate, paisesFromEntity, data.entities);
```

That's fine but I now I'm getting this input also:

```
{
   "success":true,
   "entities":{
      "id":5,
      "nombre":"dgdfgdfg",
      "direccion":"5654645",
      "telefono":"656546",
      "pais":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "nombre":"Argentina"
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "nombre":"Bolivia"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Which differs a bit from the first input so script on this case is not working because the `pais` key is missing. Can any help me to get ride of this? I can't change the server side that returns the new JSON.

```
var fullList = [];

$(document).ready(function(){
  var uniq = function (arr) {
        var ids = {};
        arr.forEach(function(obj) { 
          objPais = obj.pais.id === "undefined" ? obj.id : obj.pais.id;
          ids[objPais] = obj; 
        });
        return Object.keys(ids).map(function(id) {
          return ids[id];
        });
      };

  function showList(selector) {
      var items = [].slice.call(arguments, 1).filter(function(item) { return item; }),
        arr = fullList.concat.apply(fullList, items),
        list = uniq(arr),
        spans = list.map(function(val, i) { 
          return '<span id="' + val.pais.id +'">' + val.pais.nombre + '</span>';
        });

      if ($(selector).text().length >0) { 
        $(selector).append(', '); 
      }

      $(selector).append(spans.join(', '));
  }

  $("#btn1").on("click", function(){
    var arr1 = [{"pais":{"id":1,"nombre":"Country1"}},{"pais":{"id":2,"nombre":"Country2"}}],
        arr2 = [{"pais":{"id":1,"nombre":"Country1"}},{"pais":{"id":3,"nombre":"Country3"}},{"pais":{"id":4,"nombre":"Country4"}}],
        arr3 =[{"pais":[{"id":1,"nombre":"Argentina"},{"id":2,"nombre":"Bolivia"}]}];

    showList('#update', arr1, undefined, arr2, arr3);
  });

  $("#btn2").on("click", function(){
    var arr3 = [{"pais":{"id":5,"nombre":"Country5"}},{"pais":{"id":6,"nombre":"Country6"}}],
        arr4 = [{"pais":{"id":7,"nombre":"Country7"}},{"pais":{"id":8,"nombre":"Country8"}}];
    showList('#update', arr3, arr4);
  }); 
});
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/ruxidaxuxu/1/edit?js,output) is a jsBin working code

Comment: Do you want it to work with both input versions or only the second?

Comment: @matty with both, for the first one code works but for the second one doesn't so the idea is to make the script compatible with both inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform second format to first format:

```
arr3copy = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr3[0].pais.length; i++) {
    arr3copy.push({"pais":{"id":arr3[0].pais[i].id,"nombre":arr3[0].pais[i].nombre}});
};
arr3 = arr3copy;
```

Comment: I'm getting `arr3copy` as undefined, see [here](http://jsbin.com/ruxidaxuxu/1/edit?js,output)

Comment: should be `arr3copy = []`